# Import data and show data not working in jupyter lab

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I am currently trying to build a machine learning model through watching a youtube video online, I am currently following the intro steps, downloaded juypter-lab and have imported the needed libraries and have tried to use the "data" command so that it can read the "housing.csv" file. However no matter how many times I try there is no data chart generated like in the tutorial video please help me figure out what the issue is.

It also seems as if the program did not even recognize the 4 import library commands

*Edit: I think there is a problem with my workspace? Whenever I click run nothing happens

[[Tutorial jupyter-lab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4acB.png)]

[My Jupyter-lab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cnaT.png)

I have tried watching videos on solving the problem for 30 minutes without a solution so far

Comment: The asterisks in front of the lines means Python is still computing these lines. You need to wait until execution is finished, which will be indicated by numbers instead of the asterisks. If it does not finish or takes too long, something is wrong with your environment.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You aren't getting in messages in a terminal when you trigger running JupyterLab? What happens when you do `Run All` under `Run`?  If you don't want to sort this out right, or would like to have something to compare to that should work to read in your `.cvs` data file, you can launch into JupyterLab by going to [this link](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements) and pressing `launch binder`. Pandas is already installed in the session that will come up.  You'll just need to drag your `.cvs` file into the file panel on the left. Or you can even drag in the notebook you already started.

Comment: <continued> Dragging in your notebook you already made will save you re-writing the code but you could also open a new notebook and copy-paste your code from your local machine into the notebook running remotely. These remote sessions are only temporary. They time out without activity. Given the temporary nature make sure to save anything you make that is useful back to your own local machine. One the sessions is disconnected there is no way to access the session ever again. You can start a new one to continue. The computational power is limited but it is free and doesn't require a login.